# Conversion for NSString to NSDecimalNumber in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdecimalnumber

What is the conversion for NSString to NSDecimalNumber?

```
unsigned long long order;

if (i==1) {
    order = [feeArray objectAtIndex:0];
}
if (i==2) {
    order = [amountArray objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `NSDecimalNumber`'s `decimalNumberWithString` initializer to convert from a string

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
NSString *order = @"";
if (i==1) {
  order = [feeArray objectAtIndex:0];
}
if (i==2) {
  order = [amountArray objectAtIndex:0];
}

NSDecimalNumber *decimal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:order];
```