# Decimal values get remove when convert from String to Decimal in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, swift3, nsdecimalnumber

Please check this example

```
 let strValue = "12.00"
 let decimalValue = Decimal(string: strValue) // 12
```

it always returns 12 not 12.00 
I also try with `NSNumber`, `Float`, and `Double` but it always remove zeros.

Can you please help me with this thanks in advance

Comment: What's the point of it? What are you aiming to achieve?

Comment: I want 12.00 in form of nsdecimalnumber means my string value is 12.0000 then in decimal it gives 12 but I won't 12.0000 got ?

Comment: `12` and `12.00` are the *same numbers.* If you want to *present* the number with fractional digits then use a number formatter.

Comment: Pleas help me I spend my whole day for this but I don't get any solution till I'm trying ! Thank You

Comment: Values will be stored without zeros. But you can print as you need. Try formatted string. `String(format: "%.2f", floatValue)`.

Comment: Hello Martin, I use number formatter but it working when we return String not for DecimalNUmber and in number formatter we need to assign minimum and maximum decimal number but in my case that depend on user they can write 4 zero or 10 zero so now what should I do .?

Comment: Hello Krishna, as said I need this in format of decimal number not in string.

Comment: Again: As *numbers* there is no difference between 12 and 12.00, so your question is unclear. Just try `print(12 == 12.00)`

Comment: I don't understand why you need to represent the number 12 as 12.00 since they're the same. The only reason to do this would be to display something to the user, but then you should use @LalKrishna's solution.

Comment: because user is enter manually and in my db value is store in decimal format not in string that's why

Comment: Hello Martin, I know there is no difference but I want to save this In decimal format and if I edit this value then it now show me 12.00 it shows me 12. understood or I explain more. because I need this in decimal format in working when it 12.01 not in 12.00. Thank You

Comment: Please don't downvote the question if I'm wrong then please tell me so I can correct that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like martin said. 12 and 12.00 is the same number. It doesn't mathematical matter how many 0 are behind the comma.

While a number stays the same, the representation is a different topic.

String(format: "%.6f", 12) will give 12.000000 as String.

Edit:
A Decimal is a Struct. The meaning of the numbers stays the same. Throw this in a playground.

```
import UIKit
let decimal = Decimal(12.0000000000)
let justAnInt = 12

let sameDecimal = decimal == Decimal(justAnInt)
```

See? There is no such thing as infinite 0 in math. Zero is finite. A Decimal from 12.000000 and a Decimal created from 12 are the same.

[image]

Comment: I want this in decimal number not in string . like 12.000000

Comment: Yes I agree with mark statement but I need which number that proper number I want in decimal.

Comment: A Decimalist just a Struct that will have the very same information as an Int or Double

Comment: Hello Helge Becker, i'm not understand what you said I know struct . can you please explain me briefly so I can do solve this issue ?. Thanks

Comment: See edit. To solve your problem try to think the other way around. If you are working with decimals, accept they store only relevant informations (a list of 0 is not). Instead, why or where do u need the 12 with many 0?

Comment: @HelgeBecker  i understood you are totally right but can we get 12.00 as Decimal? is it possible?

Comment: Yes I have textfield user enter value there And there 2 options 1. Percentage 2. Amount if user enter manually like 17.00 then I have to store this value in DB and in my db I'm storing this value as decimal number not string that's why I need this. I hope you got my query. can please help me on this how can I survive in this situation thank you !

Comment: @YogeshPatel: If you store the number as “decimal” (or double, float, ...) then this information is **lost.** That's what I tried to explain from the beginning. If you need to preserve the information that the user entered "17.00" with two fractional digits then you have to store it as a *string.*

Comment: Okay I got this but I have multiple list so how can I maintain this flow. if I show 17.00 and I edit then it show me 17 because of storing value in decimal and it store 17 Got ?

Comment: Sorry I disturb you but still i need dynamic solution for that I completely understand your way.

Comment: Thank You @HelgeBecker And Martin R

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between `12` & `12.00`.
The only thing we need is to present the value to user., for that you could use formatted string.

Like:

```
String(format: "%.2f", floatValue)
```

Comment: can you please give me this value as decimal because you write %2 and for my case it not fixed it depends on user ! Thank You